# How to specify vault endpoint In springboot vault configuration without application name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

In spring boot I wanted to read the properties from vault but I wanted to read vaulr secret token and the full path of the configuration endpoint from environment variable. 
But if I give `spring.cloud.vault.uri` it is not working and for fetching from environmental variable I am using ${VAULT_TOKEN} but this also, not working.

```
spring.cloud.vault.uri=http://127.0.0.1:8200/secret/gs-vault-config/cloud/test
spring.cloud.vault.token=${VAULT_TOKEN}
```

I wanted to fetch both `spring.cloud.vault.uri` and `spring.cloud.vault.token` from environmental variable.

Comment: Did you put them in application.properties?

Comment: Yeah I tried it gave exception, spring vault reads from bootstrap.properties

Comment: Where did you put them ? under the ressources folder?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea.

Usually the file `bootstrap.properties`/`bootstrap.yaml` is placed separately from the project (project in /src, bootstrap config file in /config). It allows us to use it without rebuilding the project on parameter changes, and to use a dynamic configuration.

We already have a file with dynamic content, you want to create a separate dynamic config file with values for base dynamic config file! Tautology!